# How to suppress the “OS X Spotlight search information was removed” warning?

Tags: macos, pages

Whenever I open an old Pages document in Pages 5, I now get the following warning message:

> **Some changes were made to your document.**
>
> OS X Spotlight search information was removed.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to suppress this annoying and useless warning forever? Like, a shell script I can run on a list of documents to remove the search information all in one go? (I assumed `xattr` would help with this, but I couldn’t find any specific metadata on the files.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply save the document and you will be asked if you want to upgrade. Click "Agree" and the next time you open the document there will no longer be any warning.

Comment: I know that :) The question is, how can I do this automatically for thousands of documents? I don’t want to click thousands of times.